# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, to-date

I am getting date in html 5 input type = "date" format..in mm/dd/yyyy format. Then I am getting it `String fDate = request.getParameter("fromDate");`

room.setFromDate(fDate);

Then while trying to run query

```
insert into tbl_room_under_maintenance(room_id,room_number,from_date,to_date)
values(?,?,to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY'))

PS1.setString(3,room.getFromDate().trim());
PS1.setString(4,room.getToDate().trim());
```

it shows error : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: did you check what is the value that you get from getFromDate().trim())?

Comment: You either do *not* get the date in the format you think, or it indeed contains an invalid month.

Comment: add the output of printing `fDate` in the post

Comment: There's no need to add the data @Pat; as the problem is the data the only answer anyone is going to be able to give the OP is to point out the '36' (or whatever it is) is not a month.., which isn't very useful for anyone in the future.

Comment: @Ben It was precisely the reason I asked for data :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date before insert:

```
String fDate = request.getParameter("fromDate");
SimpleDateFormat sm = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
Date dat = sm.parse(fDate);
insert into tbl_room_under_maintenance(room_id,room_number,from_date,to_date)
values(?,?,?,?)
PS1.setDate(3,dat);
```