# to_date inside callablestatement

Tags: java, oracle, to-date

I'm trying to use a `to_date` function inside a `callableStatement`.

My statement ends up being

```
RGPKG.PKG_RG_LEAD.ADD_LEAD('TO_DATE('05-Aug-2014 11:53:34 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')',
                            <More-parameters-here>)
```

I'm using the following code to build up the `TO_DATE` function:

```
CallableStatement stmt
String dateParam =  "TO_DATE('" + sTS + "', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')";
stmt.setString(1, dateParam);    
//set more parameters
stmt.execute();
```

Where `sTS` is a string in the right date format. I can see that the problem is that the `setString` is wrapping my string in single quotes, but how do I set this on the callable statement?

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY PKG_RG_LEAD AS

PROCEDURE ADD_LEAD
 (p_created_tstamp IN RG_LEAD.CREATED_TSTAMP%type,
  p_created_by     IN RG_LEAD.CREATED_BY%type,
```

And the column on the database is created as

```
CREATED_TSTAMP  TIMESTAMP(6)    No  systimestamp    2
```

Comment: What is the `stmt` query - does that have single quotes around the placeholders? Why isn't the `to_date` itself part of the query?

Comment: stmt is a CallableStatment, it's calling package ADD_LEAD

Comment: What is the specifiction for `ADD_LEAD`? Are you trying to pass a date, or a string that the procedure will evaluate to form a date? That would be... odd.

Comment: It takes a string for parameter 1. The database has recently changed and now the default date format is different. It used to just pass a string as the date but now that doesn't work, hence wanting to use TO_DATE

Comment: You should change the procedure to take a date parameter. If you really can't do that, set your sessions `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or pass the string in the format the database now expects. Passing a function call *as the parameter* won't work.

Comment: So it takes a timestamp as a parameter, not a string. You should pass the correct native type, with `stmt.setTimestamp()`, not pass a string and rely on implicit conversion - which seems to be what you were doing before.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't want to convert your string into date and then send it to your procedure? I have answered [similar question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104784/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-error/25105465#25105465)

Comment: The package currently takes a string for parameter 1 and I would like to avoid changing it if possible. This is to avoid problems as the date format of the database has changed.

Comment: Show us the package source, at least its signature.

Comment: PROCEDURE ADD_LEAD
 (p_created_tstamp IN RG_LEAD.CREATED_TSTAMP%type,
  p_created_by     IN RG_LEAD.CREATED_BY%type,

Comment: @MikeMcK it would've been better if you added it to you question. Also show us what are RG_LEAD.CREATED_TSTAMP and RG_LEAD.CREATED_BY?

Comment: @MikeMcK your procedure `ADD_LEAD` takes timestamp in the input, I don't understand where is the obstacle if you convert you string into date before, in your java code and then pass it to your `add_lead` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on passing a string into the call, your statement should be:

```
RGPKG.PKG_RG_LEAD.ADD_LEAD(TO_TIMESTAMP(?, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'), ?, ...)
```

Then you can set the value with:

```
stmt.setString(1, sTS);
```

You need `to_timestamp()` rather than `to_date()` if you want fractional seconds and the `XFF` part of the format mask, although your sample values doesn't have fractional seconds anyway.

But it would be much better to pass an actual timestamp value, using `stmt.setTimestamp()` as zaratustra suggests. Here's an example:

```
String sTS = "05-Aug-2014 11:53:34 AM";

stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call RGPKG.PKG_RG_LEAD.ADD_LEAD(?, ?, ...) }";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
stmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(sdf.parse(sTS).getTime()));
...
```

If your actual value does have fraction seconds then make the format `"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.S a"`.